# How to Chnage the styling of product Variations using shopify App. Theme App Extension

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-template, shopify-storefront-api

I have started learning Shopify app development and have learned many things, but now I am stuck on changing the **styles** of **product variations**. Shopify requires that your app should have a **theme app extension** so your app won't leave ghost code behind when uninstalled. (simplified e.g)

I have seen many apps with the same functionality that I want. For example, "The main **App page** will allow users to change the style of variations, and after that, users have to save the changes. Then, if the App is enabled from the **App embed** section, only then will it change the appearance of **Product variations**." You can check out **Globo Color Swatch**, which I like.

#### 2 Questions:

1. I currently don't understand how all this works, like where I need to make changes. (In the main **App** or in the **Theme app extension**?)
2. I want to know how I can change the styles of product variations (like **shape**, **size**, **hover effect**) using theme app extension or App or Both .

I am using Shopify **Remix** template not **node**.

Any help would be appreciated!

1: I have tried the Rest api that creates product variations or updates it but it won't and can't change the styles.